# Repeating edges of image upon user zooming out

Tags: html, image, css, css-float

I have an image I want to be the full width of my screen for my wordpress website. I also want to make it so when the user zooms out it takes the edges of that image (for example lets say the image is of width 800, then it would take the 0-100 px on the left side and maybe the 700-800 px for the right) and repeat those, as well as being responsive. I figure thats impossible with strictly code so if I had photoshopped the edges I want repeated, how would I go about overlaying these 3 images and having them behave accordingly. Is this possible? the picture is basically of the sky, and its mostly clear with maybe a cloud so it would look ok repeated :)

I haven't tried it with code and I'm a bit newby to css so I would love some advice on how to do it! Right now I just have a div class with a background url and its width is 100% but it repeats when I zoom out.

Here's an image of what I'm talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling I came up with the following solution that utilizes the `:before` and `:after` CSS pseudo-elements, which allows my solution to work without adding any additional elements. This example uses an image with an original width of `800px` and a height of `300px`. Because of this, the middle part is `600px`, and the side images are `100px` wide. Alter these numbers in the following CSS to fit your image size. [See a working jsFiddle demo with a poorly drawn cloud.](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/k756936g/)

```
<div class="header"></div>
```

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url('http://example.com/path/to/center-image.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header:before,
.header:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 300px;
    width: calc((100% - 600px) / 2);
}
.header:before {
    left: calc((100% - 600px) / 2 - (100% - 600px) / 2);
    background-image: url('http://example.com/path/to/left-image.png');
}
.header:after {
    right: calc((100% - 600px) / 2 - (100% - 600px) / 2);
    background-image: url('http://example.com/path/to/right-image.png');
}
```

Comment: wonderful! this worked perfectly! now to brush up on my photoshop skills and make it actually look decent :p